# Why am I getting this RelayState error? (AWS third-party SAML)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml, saml-2.0, idp

I'm trying to set up a third party SAML with AWS Cognito. When I try to login from my local environment, it works perfectly.

The problem is when I try to access it from my workplaces' SSO IdP dashboard.

I keep getting the following error: `Required String parameter 'RelayState' is not present`

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

PS. I have set up the SSO IdP dashboard with an ACS URL and Entity ID as per these docs: [AWS DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-integrating-3rd-party-saml-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which IdP you use, you must configure the Default Relay state on the IdP side.

You can append the RelayState to the IdP SSO URL as `?RelayState=relay-state-here`.